# WPF: Find Resources from UserControl within DataTemplateSelector class

Tags: wpf, user-controls, resources, datatemplateselector

I know there is this thread: [How to find a resource in a UserControl from a DataTemplateSelector class in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916012/how-to-find-a-resource-in-a-usercontrol-from-a-datatemplateselector-class-in-wpf)

asking the same.

BUT... I am not satisfied with the answer! THERE MUST be a way to grab the Resources of the

UserControl containing the ContentControl/Presenter declaring this:

```
ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MySelector}"
```

Each derived `DataTemplateSelector` class a parameter in its `SelectedTemplate` Method =>

container which is typeof DependencyObject.

Well container is in my case the contentcontrol.

*Would it not be possible to climb up the visual tree starting at "contentcontrol" and try
to get the UserControl via FindAncestor ?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can cast the `container` parameter to `FrameworkElement` and call [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) to do a resource lookup starting at the `ContentPresenter`.  For example:

Code:

```
public class MySelector
    : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate
        (object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        // Determine the resource key to use
        var key = item.ToString() == "a" ? "one" : "two";
        // Find the resource starting from the container
        return ((FrameworkElement)container).FindResource(key) as DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="one">
            <TextBlock>Template One</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="two">
            <TextBlock>Template Two</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:MySelector x:Key="MySelector"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter
            ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MySelector}"
            Content="a"/>
        <ContentPresenter
            ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MySelector}"
            Content="b"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: works!!! I put your solution also in the other thread with the bad solution so maybe you get more points ;-)